# How to convert CSV string to integer and add it. store ing txtfile

Tags: java, string, csv, integer

can you help me to this, I wanted to add 2 integer coming from CSV and store it in txtfile, but the problem is it was string and if i convert it to an integer i've gots lots of error.. Thank you guys..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVReader {
public static void main (String[]arg)throws Exception {

    String readFile = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/student.csv";
    String writeFile = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/data.txt";

    // Read a comma-separated values (CSV) file.
    BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(readFile));

    // Read line.
    String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();

    // Create an array of student
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList <Student> ();


    // The while checks to see if the data is null. If
    // it is, we’ve hit the end of the file. If not,
    // process the data.
    while (dataRow !=null){
        String [] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
        System.out.println(dataRow);
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setStudentName(dataArray[0]);
        student.setScore1(dataArray[1]);
        student.setScore2(dataArray[2]);
        students.add(student);
        dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
        }

    // Close the file once all data has been read.
    CSVFile.close();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(writeFile);
    for (Student s : students){
        sb.append(s.studentName);
        System.out.println(s.studentName + " - " + (s.score1 + s.score2));

        // Writing to a text file.
        fw.write(sb.toString());
    }

    // Close the file once all data has been written.
    fw.close(); 
}

}
```

output:

```
  che,cheche,chet
  100,100,100
  100,100,100
  null - 0
  null - 0
  null - 0
```

it should br:

```
  che,cheche,chet
  100,100,100
  100,100,100
  che - 200
  cheche -200
  chet - 200
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you tell us which errors.

Comment: how do you convert the string to integer ?

Comment: Try student.setScore1(Integer.parseInt(dataArray[1]));

Comment: @Jayamohan i'd try it but it does not work.

Comment: @OblTobl theres no error.. my concern is that the output of the System.out.println(s.studentName + " - " + (s.score1 + s.score2));    this is the output : "che,cheche,chet
100,100,100
100,100,100
null - 0
null - 0"
null - 0

Comment: this what i need to display: che-200, checeh-200, chet-200

Comment: has nothing to do with converting to int. Check the answer of @jesus.tesh, he points you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

If the info you have provided is correct, then the main issue you have is the CSV data is in a columnar format, rather than a typical row format. By that, I mean the first row is name, with the next rows the scores. Each "column" of data matches up with the "header" at the same index.

**Your example data:**

```
che, cheche, chet    -- row[0]
100, 100,    100     -- row[1]
100, 100,    100     -- row[2]
```

So row[0] is the name, but you are parsing te data as if the 1st item of a row is the name, and the 2nd and 3rd items are scores - which is not the case based on this sample data.

If you wanted scores you'd need to get the proper index for each row - so che would be row[1][0] and row[2][0].

If this is in fact the case, then you'll want to process the first row to get the names, then you'll want to process the remaining rows to get the scores.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
int number = Integer.parseInt("your string here");
```

Example:

```
   String one = "1";
   String two = "2";
   System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(one) + Integer.parseInt(two));
```

Comment: It is for adding the two integer values.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood your post ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have made few mistakes in the code.

1. The score variables in the student class should be integer.
2. To convert a string to Integer you need to use Integer.parseInt
   method. Ideally your conversion should be at the stage when you are
   setting the score values.
3. Why are you adding student object to an ArrayList. Can't you
   directly write to the text file?